# How to add a character at the end of each line with awk?

Tags: awk

I would like to add character `A` at the end of each line in a text file. How can I do this with awk?

```
1AAB
VBNM
JHTF
2SDA
```

Desired output

```
1AABA
VBNMA
JHTFA
2SDAA
```

Comment: You can do this pretty easily with sed - `sed -i 's/$/A/' file.txt`

Comment: Be careful to ```-i``` flag, it overrides file.txt in-place

Comment: You can use this ```sed -e '1 s/$/400/' -e '2 s/$/401/' -e '3 s/$/402/' -e '4 s/$/403/' file.txt``` to add at end of each line a specified character (e.g., here I used numbers 400-403). The number 1,2, and 3 reflects the line index.

Answer (score 63):

this may do the job for you

```
awk '{print $0"A"}' yourFile
```

Comment: If you don't want to hard-code the character, you can pass it to awk: `awk -v char=A '{print $0 char}' file`

Comment: not sure where to put this, but this `'{print $0"A"}'` resulted in an extra newline output after each `$0` for some reason. This baffled me. Somehow a `\n\r` got inserted after each `$0`. I solved this issue using `tr` afterwards. Something like this `./script.awk -F $'\t' file.tsv | tr "\n\r" ""` might work for you

Comment: Getting some weird results here:
`awk '{print $0"A"}' yourFile`
----
`1AABA
VBNMA
JHTFA
2SDAA`

As expected.  However:

`awk '{print $0"A"}' foo.txt`

Puts the "A" at the beginning of each line.

`Aser_id,count_seen
A,44
A,18603
A,87452
A,16572`

Comment: I think the weird behaviour is because of trailing "\r" character. You can solve it by doing `sed 's/\r//g' foo.txt | awk '{print $0",1"}'`

Comment: @guillefix Great! This is exactly what I am looking for.