# inserting text around a list of things

Tags: ruby, awk, sed

This is something simple that, for some reason is eluding me. I should think I should be able to do this from the bash prompt with a very simple script or one-liner.

I have a file, consisting of a list of numbers:

```
12345
23456
34567
45678
```

Very simple. I want to change it to:

```
arglebargle-12345-fulferol-12345-applesauce
arglebargle-23456-fulferol-23456-applesauce
arglebargle-34567-fulferol-34567-applesauce
arglebargle-45678-fulferol-45678-applesauce
```

So... insert a string on both sides of a number (or a string, it just happens that these strings are numbers, it is not essential that they be numbers)... then append the original string, and put a third string after that.

I think I would prefer to do this in sed or awk as a one-liner. Or as a ruby script. It should be so easy, and it is evading my mind for some reason!

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
echo "12345
> 23456
> 34567
> 45678" | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/arglebargle-\1-fulferol-\1-applesauce/g'

arglebargle-12345-fulferol-12345-applesauce
arglebargle-23456-fulferol-23456-applesauce
arglebargle-34567-fulferol-34567-applesauce
arglebargle-45678-fulferol-45678-applesauce
```

If you want to substitute in place in a file(where your file is `a.txt` for example) you can do

```
sed -i 's/\(.*\)/arglebargle-\1-fulferol-\1-applesauce/g' a.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
nums = %w(12345 23456 34567 45678)
nums.each { |num| puts "arglebargle-#{num}-fulferol-#{num}-applesauce" }
```

Output:

```
arglebargle-12345-fulferol-12345-applesauce
arglebargle-23456-fulferol-23456-applesauce
arglebargle-34567-fulferol-34567-applesauce
arglebargle-45678-fulferol-45678-applesauce
```

Answer (score 1):

This should accomplish the job:

```
awk '{ print "arglebargle-" $0 "-fulferol-" $0 "-applesauce" }' numFile
```

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455116/how-to-add-a-character-at-the-end-of-each-line-with-awk).